# Morphia error: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am trying to learn MongoDB and Morphia and I have created a sample application in Java.
But while performing aggregation I am getting "invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId" error.

Morphia version is 1.3.2

**Entity: Address.java**

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Property("id")
    protected ObjectId id;

    private String street;

    private String building;

    private String pin;
}
```

**Sample document:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58fcb704c1d24e05ce5851cb"),
    "building" : "SGV",
    "street" : "Galaxy Heights",
    "pin" : "411017"
}
```

**AddressDAO.java:**

```
public class AddressDAO extends BasicDAO<Address, ObjectId>{

    public AddressDAO(Class<Address> entityClass, Datastore ds) {
        super(entityClass, ds);
    } 

    public List<Address> getByGroupedData(String pin) {

        Query<Address> query = createQuery().field("pin").equal(pin);
        Iterator<Address> pipeline = getDatastore().createAggregation(Address.class)
                .match(query)
                .group(Group.id(Group.grouping("building"))).out(Address.class);


        while(pipeline.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(pipeline.next());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When calling 'pipeline.next()' in AddressDAO.java I am getting the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [{ "building" : "Galaxy Heights"}]
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.parseHexString(ObjectId.java:550)
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(ObjectId.java:240)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.ObjectIdConverter.decode(ObjectIdConverter.java:32)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.Converters.fromDBObject(Converters.java:124)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.ValueMapper.fromDBObject(ValueMapper.java:20)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:844)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:282)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:193)
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is with the `$out` stage. It creates the new collection with _id field as `building` value.

So now when you try to map it back to `Address` object which has `_id` defined as Object id, it results in an error.

So the fix would be to use `$projection` to suppress the  `_id` field from the final response so the $out stage creates a new Object id.

Try something like this.

```
Iterator<Address> pipeline = getDatastore().createAggregation(Address.class)
                .match(query)
                .group(Group.id(Group.grouping("building")))
                .project(Projection.projection("_id").suppress(), Projection.projection("building", "$_id"))
                .out(Address.class);
```

Sidenote: You probably should map into new pojo object for new collection.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and let you know. Thanks Veeram.

Comment: Upvoted. I am still working on it after few days break